# Django get all the latest values of unique entries of a column in a Table

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get all the latest values of unique entries of a column in a Table. For Example I have a table like this, which is called Test

```
|____id|____fk1|__created|
|     1|      1|    Nov 5|
|     2|      1|    Nov 2|
|     3|      1|    Nov 1|
|     4|      2|    Nov 4|
|     5|      3|    Nov 9|
|     6|      3|    Nov 7|
```

Now I want to get all the entries in the table with unique 'fk1' values but the row where the 'created' column has the latest date. I want Django to return the queryset of the following rows

```
|____id|____fk1|__created|
|     1|      1|    Nov 5|
|     4|      2|    Nov 4|
|     5|      3|    Nov 9|
```

What is a efficient Django way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.distinct(**fields)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in your query for that

example:

```
YourModel.objects.order_by('created').distinct('fk1')
```

Comment: What would you filter though, every date will be different. You need the latest of each date for the corresponding value in 'fk1'

Comment: @dracarys it's just an example though, the main thing is if you want a field to be unique in the query you would use distinct() at the end of the query

Comment: Ya I get that but using order_by would result in O(n log n) implementation, was wondering if there is a faster way to do this

Comment: @dracarys i think as for queryset of orm order_by() is the fastest one that i know of, if you want to be faster then you can index your order_by() column as describe in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques , but you should read first the con of indexing column

Comment: This is really helpful, I implemented it and it was pretty fast. I will see if indexing helps it or not after evaluating the cons of it